# React - You have provided an out-of-range value `undefined` for the select component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui

I'm creating a material-UI dialogue form that `posts` data to my API. One of the fields in my backend database is binary and takes in only two possible options. How can I reflect that in my dialogue code below?

Here is my Fulltrace Back error:

> Material-UI: You have provided an out-of-range value `undefined` for
> the select (name="category") component. Consider providing a  value
> that matches one of the available options or ''. The available values
> are `personal`, `social`.

The possible options for this specific field are either `personal` or `social`.

I tried doing this, letting my dialogue push the correct responses:

```
<MenuItem value={'personal'}> personal </MenuItem>
<MenuItem value={'social'}> social </MenuItem>
```

But that does not work and I understand why. Just not sure how to solve the error now as I'm not too savvy with React/JS in general.

```
export default function CreateBucket() {
    const [open, setOpen] = React.useState(false);

    const handleClickOpen = () => {
      setOpen(true);
    };
  
    const handleClose = () => {
      setOpen(false);
    };
  

    const history = useHistory();
    const initialFormData = Object.freeze({
        name: '',
        category: '',
        about: '',
    });

    const [formData, updateFormData] = useState(initialFormData);

    const handleChange = (e) => {
        updateFormData({
            ...formData,
            // Trimming any whitespace
            [e.target.name]: e.target.value.trim(),
        });
    };

    const handleSubmit = (e) => {
        e.preventDefault();
        console.log(formData);

        axiosInstance
            .post(`create/bucket`, {
                name: formData.name,
                category: formData.category,
                about: formData.about,
            })
            .then((res) => {
                history.push('/');
                console.log(res);
                console.log(res.data);
            });
    };

    const classes = useStyles();

    return(
        <Fragment>
        <Fab color="primary" aria-label="add"  onClick={handleClickOpen} variant="extended">
        <AddIcon className={classes.extendedIcon}/>
        Create Bucket
        </Fab>
        <Dialog open={open} onClose={handleClose} aria-labelledby="form-dialog-title">
        <DialogTitle id="form-dialog-title">Create your Bucket</DialogTitle>
        <DialogContent>
            <DialogContentText>
            Get started! Make your bucket by telling us a little bit more.
            </DialogContentText>
                <form>            
                <FormControl>
                <InputLabel> What type of Bucket </InputLabel>
                <Select
                id="category"
                label="Bucket Type"
                name="category"
                fullWidth
                required
                variant="filled"
                onChange={handleChange}
                margin="normal"
                className={classes.formControl}
                >
                <MenuItem value={'personal'}> personal </MenuItem>
                <MenuItem value={'social'}> social </MenuItem>
                </Select>
                </FormControl>
                </form>
            </DialogContent>
            <DialogActions>
            <Button 
            type="submit"
            fullWidth
            variant="contained"
            color="primary"
            className={classes.submit}
            onClick={handleSubmit}
            >
            Create Bucket
            </Button>
        </DialogActions>
        </Dialog>
    </Fragment>  
    );
}
```

How can I implement changes to solve my traceback error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is exactly what it says on the tin:

> Material-UI: You have provided an out-of-range value undefined for the select (name="category") component. Consider providing a value that matches one of the available options or ''. The available values are personal, social.

When you create a Select it wants you to provide initial value, which can be `personal`, `social` or an empty string. You don't provide any value, so it get confused

```
 <Select
            id="category"
            value={formData.category}
            label="Bucket Type"
```

will make it stop complaining.

Comment: Thank you for your help, I mentioned to Raphael's comment above, that when I add `value=""` to the `<select>`. The user is not able to populate the actual field, they can see the dropdown options, but when they select, the item does not seem to visually present itself in the field.

Comment: Try `{formData.category}` instead

Answer (score 5):

Make sure you provide `value` prop to `<Select>` component, put `value=""` in case you don't want any of the options to be selected by default or `value="personal"` in case you want personal to be selected by default.

Her is mine with `value={formData.category}` it takes the value selected from state.

```
export default function CreateBucket() {
  const [open, setOpen] = React.useState(false);

  const handleClickOpen = () => {
    setOpen(true);
  };
  
  const handleClose = () => {
    setOpen(false);
  };
  

  const history = useHistory();
  const initialFormData = Object.freeze({
    name: '',
    category: '',
    about: '',
  });

  const [formData, updateFormData] = useState(initialFormData);

  const handleChange = (e) => {
    updateFormData({
      ...formData,
      // Trimming any whitespace
      [e.target.name]: e.target.value.trim(),
    });
  };

  const handleSubmit = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    console.log(formData);

    axiosInstance
      .post(`create/bucket`, {
        name: formData.name,
        category: formData.category,
        about: formData.about,
      })
      .then((res) => {
        history.push('/');
        console.log(res);
        console.log(res.data);
      });
  };

  const classes = useStyles();

  return(
    <Fragment>
      <Fab color="primary" aria-label="add"  onClick={handleClickOpen} variant="extended">
        <AddIcon className={classes.extendedIcon}/>
        Create Bucket
      </Fab>
      <Dialog open={open} onClose={handleClose} aria-labelledby="form-dialog-title">
        <DialogTitle id="form-dialog-title">Create your Bucket</DialogTitle>
        <DialogContent>
          <DialogContentText>
            Get started! Make your bucket by telling us a little bit more.
          </DialogContentText>
          <form>            
            <FormControl>
              <InputLabel> What type of Bucket </InputLabel>
              <Select
                id="category"
                label="Bucket Type"
                name="category"
                fullWidth
                required
                variant="filled"
                onChange={handleChange}
                margin="normal"
                value={formData.category}
                className={classes.formControl}
              >
                <MenuItem value={'personal'}> personal </MenuItem>
                <MenuItem value={'social'}> social </MenuItem>
              </Select>
            </FormControl>
          </form>
        </DialogContent>
        <DialogActions>
          <Button 
            type="submit"
            fullWidth
            variant="contained"
            color="primary"
            className={classes.submit}
            onClick={handleSubmit}
          >
            Create Bucket
          </Button>
        </DialogActions>
      </Dialog>
    </Fragment>  
  );
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your comment, did not know the solution was that simple! When I add `value=""`, to `<select>`, there seems to be nothing that actually adds to the field. Meaning, if a user selects one of the options, the field does not get populated.

Comment: That's because we didn't add control value to the Select component - `formData.category`.

Answer (score 0):

None of these solved my issue where I wanted to have a placeholder but I have a state value and an onChange event inside my textfield. Once you set the initial state you cannot have a placeholder.

My fix below is to have the value of 'place holder text' in initial state and inside the list of options. I disabled and grayed out the value once initially loaded so it looks like a placeholder.

```
<TextField
   margin="dense"
   select
   fullWidth
   placeholder='Fuel Type'
   value={fuelType}
   onChange={handleFuelChange}
   // defaultValue="Fuel Type"
   type="text"
   name="fuelType"
   >
   {options3.map((option) => {
   return (option.label === "Fuel Type" ? <MenuItem key={option.label} disabled value={option.label + "," + option.carbonFactor}>
   <span style={{ color: "rgb(156, 156, 156)" }}>{option.label}</span>
   </MenuItem> : <MenuItem key={option.label} value={option.label + "," + option.carbonFactor}>
   {option.label}
   </MenuItem>)
   })}
</TextField>
```